# Java & Postgres Multi-threading Failure

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, database-connection

### Context

Spring Batch Application & Postgres are hosted on the same server.

Spring Batch Step is running in a multi-threaded manner executing SELECT queries.

The Spring Batch Step executes correctly for awhile, then randomly hits the below error while executing a query against Postgres.

### Error

```
2021-04-29 20:57:31.974 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step ECIP_TN in job ECIP_tom_JOB
com.lit.tom.core.exception.ApplicationException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at com.lit.tom.core.driver.retriever.sql.SqlRetriever.getData(SqlRetriever.java:98) ~[tom-engine-1.2.11-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.2.11-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.lit.tom.core.driver.retriever.LegacyDataRetriever.retrieveLegacyRecords(LegacyDataRetriever.java:48) ~[tom-engine-1.2.11-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.2.11-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:371) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:452) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:462) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:490) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.13.RELEASE]
        at com.lit.tom.core.driver.retriever.sql.SqlRetriever.getData(SqlRetriever.java:59) ~[tom-engine-1.2.11-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.2.11-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 78 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]

        ... 78 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Cannot assign requested address (connect failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
```

### Investigative Work

#### Postgres

Postgres is running, and accepting data on that port.

```
#Relevant postgres configuration
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'
max_connections = 100
port = 5432
```

[image: Postgres netstat]

#### Java

- The error is reached faster with more threads.
- 8, 6, 4, and 2 threads have failed.
- Single threaded runs fine.

### I'm lost on what to look at, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You hitting the max connections limit maybe? If you don't know, then as an experiment, increase it to 1000 and see if the behaviour changes.

Comment: @404 It's worth a shot, but I don't see how I could reach 100 connections with 8 active threads.

Comment: Depends how the connection lifecycle is being controlled. Are you creating the connections yourself? Are they being disposed of properly? If it's not a connection limit issue, then I can't really think of a good reason. Is pg running locally or on another server? I've done very high loads against local pg servers and never had this issue. Might also be worth checking the pg log file to see if there were any errors logged there around that time.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem, and it was in line with the comments on this post.

The max number of connections was being reached.

The error was coming from a child project, and they had changed the DataSource from HikariCP to the [DriverManagerDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html).

Relevant documentation snippet:

> NOTE: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually pool Connections. It just serves as simple replacement for a full-blown connection pool, implementing the same standard interface, but creating new Connections on every call.

The solution was to change back to HikariCP.